# Symmetric difference of a sample of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following:

```
list1={a,b,c,d};
list2={c,d,e,f};
list3={g,d,c,h};
```

Now I would like to get the [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference). Hence, the result must be `{a,b,e,f,g,h}` (whether the result is sorted or not is irrelevant)

BTW: Using `Complement[list1,list2,list3]` returns `{a,b}`, since `Complement` only "gives the elements in `e_all` which are not in any of the `e_i`." ([Mathematica Documentation Center](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Complement.html))

Comment: What you ask for is _not_ the symmetric difference. The symmetric difference of the three sets you posted is `{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
Complement[Join[list1, list2, list3], 
 Intersection[list1, list2, list3]]
```

or as suggested in the comments:

```
Complement[Union[list1, list2, list3], 
 Intersection[list1, list2, list3]]

(*
=> {a, b, e, f, g, h}
*)
```

Note, that the h is present here but not the d. I assume this is a typo in the question.

Comment: So that's the list of elements that are missing from at least one set.  Then `h` should be in the expected result too.

Comment: @Szabolcs, that's a valid point. I have updated the post.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I assume that the d<=>h is a typo. We will see what OP has to say.

Comment: Totaly what I was looking for. Thx!

Comment: @John, most welcome. May I suggest that you fix the question to reflect this?

Comment: From mathematical point of view I would rather use `Union[list1, list2, list3]` instead of `Join[list1, list2, list3]`.

Comment: @Artes, added. Thanks.

Comment: @Artes: May I ask why?

Comment: @John With the `Join` you get duplicates, while with `Union` you don't. `Union` is implementation of sum of sets, `Join` is just a concatenation of lists.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = {a, b, c, d};
y = {c, d, e, f};
z = {g, d, c, h}
```

Nowadays we get the wanted result more easily with:

```
Flatten @ UniqueElements[{x, y, z}]
```

{a, b, e, f, g, h}

As Henrik commented the question title is misleading:

```
SymmetricDifference[x, y, z]
```

{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}

`UniqueElements` and `SymmetricDifference` came with V 13.1

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `Counts` and `Select`:

```
x = {a, b, c, d};
y = {c, d, e, f};
z = {g, d, c, h};

Keys@Select[Counts[Catenate@{x, y, z}], # == 1 &]

(*{a, b, e, f, g, h}*)
```